# how to manually set nextauth.js session cookie

Tags: java, reactjs, keycloak, next-auth

I am making an "alternative" login option to a react site using nextauth.js. Site uses keycloak for authentication.
I've managed to get token from keycloak using token_endpoint api by performing direct naked imersonation (I am provided with a login with no password and have to log in that user. I know it's not a very good idea to do that.).

I am setting a secure httponly cookie named `__Secure-next-auth.session-token` with `access-token` from token.

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I am getting errors about decrypting JWT. Ok, so I try to look it up.

I found that nextauthjs uses sha256 for signing, but java 17 doesn't support sha256. What libraries support this?

How do I manually craft a cookie so that I'll be logged in properly?